# nomethoderror in index for another method with collection routes on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, slim-lang

I want to create an excel file. When i try to going on `professionals/628/medical_records` displays the following message

```
undefined method `report_medical_records_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000d0eb4f8>:0x0000000d0ea080>
```

For the following lines on template, this line is the link that must going to the route that creates de excel file.

```
.clearfix
  div.excel-export
    = link_to report_medical_records_path(format: 'xlsx'), id: 'report_medical_records_link', data: { original_href: report_medical_records_path(format: 'xlsx') } do
      i.fa.fa-file-excel-o style="margin-right:5px"
      span exportar historias
```

That's my `index` and `report` actions

```
def index
    @medical_records = MedicalRecord.for_organization(current_organization)

    medical_records_scope = @medical_records.joins(:owner,:target_user).preload(:owner,:target_user)
    medical_records_scope = medical_records_scope.like_with_target_user(params[:filter].strip) if params[:filter]
    @medical_records_list = smart_listing_create(:medical_records,
                                                 medical_records_scope,
                                                 sort_attributes: [[:name, "name"],[:profesional, "users.name"],[:target, "target_users_medical_records.name"]],
                                                 partial: 'medical_records/listing'
    )

    @medical_id = current_user.medical_id

    if params[:no_layout]=='true'
      render 'index', layout: false
    else
      render 'index'
    end
 end

def report
    medical_records_scope = begin_of_association_chain.order('active DESC')
    medical_records_scope = medical_records_scope.like(params[:filter].strip) if params[:filter]

    @medical_records_report = medical_records_scope

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx {
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="medical_records.xlsx"'
        render disposition: 'inline'
      }
    end
 end
```

And the routes:

```
resources :medical_records, controller: 'medical_records' do
      collection do
        get :report
      end
    end
```

---

### **UPDATED STATE**

> *I'll keep before question upside, so remains outdated.*

Current error message:

```
The action 'report' could not be found for MedicalRecordsController
```

Now i have this in routes:

```
resources :professionals do
    #...
    resources :medical_records, controller: 'medical_records', only: [] do
      collection do
        get :report
      end
    end
  end
```

and the `action` inside `MedicalRecordsController` is that:

```
def report
    medical_records_scope = begin_of_association_chain.order('active DESC')
    medical_records_scope = medical_records_scope.like(params[:filter].strip) if params[:filter]

    @medical_records_report = medical_records_scope

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx {
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="medical_records.xlsx"'
        render disposition: 'inline'
      }
    end
  end
```

Why cannot find the action in controller?

Comment: Have you checked `rake routes` if `report_medical_records` is listed there as expected? Can you use path helper methods at all?

Comment: is not listed running a  `rake routes` @SebastianvomMeer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved to updated question!

action was inside `private` then just move up.

Answer (score 1):

The route/action you want is not standard to rails.  You need to tell it a little more information in the routes.rb in order to get what you want, in particular, *the action*:

```
resources :medical_records, controller: 'medical_records' do
  collection do
    get :report, action: :report
  end
end
```

That will get you the following route:

```
report_medical_records GET  /medical_records/report(.:format)   medical_records#report
```

Comment: this solved a first step, now show this `The action 'report' could not be found for MedicalRecordsController`  when i click on the link that have 
`= link_to report_professional_medical_records_path(format: 'xlsx'), id: 'report_professional_medical_records_link', data: { original_href: report_professional_medical_records_path(format: 'xlsx') } do
      i.fa.fa-file-excel-o style="margin-right:5px"
      span exportar historias`

@GregTarsa

Comment: Your error message does not match your problem definition.  The problem is in terms of `report_medical_records_path` and the `#report` method is defined for the `MedicalRecordsController`, so I would expect it to be found.  Your error is coming from `report_professional_medical_records_path`.  Check out the [Rails Routing from the Outside In Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for modifications you might make to your route statement for this.

Comment: If i use `report_medica_records_path` still having the same issue from the first time, the entire root looks like this. 
`resources :professionals do
  resources :medical_records, 
   controller: 'medical_records' do
      collection do
        get :report, action: :report
      end
    end
  end`

Comment: Take a look in your log and see what `rails` is showing for the 'Started GET ...` line just before the `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` error.  I suspect you have a spelling error somewhere.